# use SIGQUIT and SIGINT

Tags: c, linux, sigint

I'm trying to solve a problem because I'm learning to use system calls in C. I used a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

The statement of the problem says that I need to implement a code that allows to execute a command (cmd2) after the correct end of other command (cmd1). Also says that user can specify both commands and all of the arguments that user wants.

At this point I create this little program:

```
#include <syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) 
{
    int cmd1 = system("sleep 5");


    if((cmd1 = (-1)))
    {
        write(1,"error in command 1",18);
    }
    if(cmd1=(0))
    {
        write(1, "hello world", 11);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Next, statement says that if the first command doesn't finish correctly the second will not execute, also, user can abort the execution of the cmd1 using Ctrl+\ or Ctrl+4 (SIGQUIT) and the second command (cmd2) using Ctrl+C (SIGINT). If second command is canceled the first must be completed normaly.

I have problems in this second part of the statement because I never used this kind of things in C and also I'm really noob in linux. I tried to read something about SIGQUIT and SIGINT but I don't understand all that I've read probably because there are a lot of things of linux that I've not learned yet.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

I edit the code for this version using if functions. It doesn't work correctly, I'm finding how to check if the first command finishes correctly.

Comment: But it's the first process you've spawned that will receive the quit or the interrupt, and will communicate that to your via its return code. Which is where you'll find success or failure too. You should look at the return value from system. (If you haven't already, look at `man system` where you'll see a code sample showing how to spot SIGINT and SIGTERM from the return code.)

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? *Can anyone help me please* is not very descriptive. I would suggest reading about [sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) if you don't know how to catch the signals.

Comment: Ok I'm going to look `man system`, also my question is what I need to do to solve my problem because I'm  lost, I'm not sure how to do to implement the second part of the statement.

Comment: signal(kill_signal, function_address), see the signal() for more information, hope this solves your problem

Comment: The code you have posted and the problem are very different. Your code is not relevant to the problem statement.

Comment: Hi guys, I edit the post with new code but I think that it's not completly correct, some suggestion?

Comment: I think what you want is the equivalent of && in bash. Am I correct ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what is && in bash, I'm new using linx and there are a lot of things unknown for me yet, I'm sure that the problem is 
relatively simply it's only that is too new for me.

Comment: @alwayslearn Have a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24684/confusing-use-of-and-operators)

Comment: @alwayslearn Wait ! Wait ! Stop using signals ! I don't think you need them !

Comment: @Mohammad Ghazanfar after read the link I think that it seems that you're correct when say that I want the equivalent of && in bash, it seems that I need something to do this. About your next comment, I use signals because the statement talks about SIGQUIT and SIGINT, with this code I can jump to the second command pressing Ctrl+C and it looks good, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78237/discussion-between-mohammad-ghazanfar-and-alwayslearn).

Comment: did anybody mention that op uses `=` as equal comparison?

Comment: ah... after all the discussion, how come nobody provided a right track to op and no importance was stressed? first of all, please fix what i have mentioned above to get `cmd1` work. then, you need to know how to trap a signal in linux, by using `sigaction` or `signal`. then, you need to know a little bit more about process model in linux. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html. now you have enough info for your homework.

Comment: `if( (cmd1=(-1)))` is not a check for equality.  It will assign the value -1 to cmd1 and always evaluate true.  You need to use `==`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I didn't point that out because the code was TOTALLY different the last time I saw. OP has been changing the code every hour !

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I don't understand why signals are required ! Could you please elaborate ? The problem statement tells that the `cmd1` can be aborted using `SIGQUIT`. It does not require you to catch this and do anything specific with it. So, I think OP doesn't have to worry about signals yet.

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar maybe i understood the question wrongly. but i think the behaviors of SIGQUIT and SIGINT are specified. so the first thing op should do is to trap both of them to customize the behaviors. how could you make it without trapping any signals?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr He doesn't need to customize the behaviors. Their default behavior is to terminate the process. So, he doesn't need to trap them. I could be wrong too !

Comment: @MohammadGhazanfar ambiguous for `SIGQUIT`, but for `SIGINT`, i think you should have cmd1 finish successfully while it's running. so you don't kill `cmd1` with `SIGINT`. just prevent `cmd2` from launching or killing it.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Hmm... Well that could be another way to interpret it...

Comment: @alwayslearn Could you please post the exact problem statement please ?

Comment: Wow, It's a hot discussion. About de statement, I copied it exactly as I have, but for the context where it is I think that I need to do your solution @Mohammad Ghazanfar but I'm not sure neither, so, I think that I'll accept your post as correct but your idea HuStmpHrrr it's also good I think, thank you all for your help and interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get you started. Let me explain the question because I feel you haven't understood it.

> The statement of the problem says that I need to implement a code that allows to execute a command (cmd2) after the correct end of other command (cmd1).

You will will be given two commands by the user `cmd1` and `cmd2`. `cmd1` should be executed first.

> Next, statement says that if the first command doesn't finish correctly the second will not execute,

**ONLY IF** `cmd1` finished executing normally should `cmd2` be executed.

> If second command is canceled the first must be completed normaly.

Execution of `cmd1` is not dependent on `cmd2`.

> user can abort the execution of the cmd1 using Ctrl+\ or Ctrl+4 (SIGQUIT)

You seem confused here. Here, they mean to say, `cmd1` can be abnormally terminated by passing SIGQUIT to it(Ctrl+\ or Ctrl+4), in which case `cmd2` should not be executed. You do **NOT** have to code the signals part. What you have to do is, check how `cmd1` was terminated and then execute `cmd2` if it was a normal termination else don't execute cmd2.

**Note** The code in the question was extremely different when the above part was posted.

---

This was your code on 5:02 AM Wednesday, 20 May 2015 GMT.(Had to include this because you are changing the code too often and too much)

```
int main(void) 
{
    int cmd1 = system("sleep 5");
    if((cmd1 = (-1)))
    {
        write(1,"error in command 1",18);
    }
    if(cmd1=(0))
    {
        write(1, "hello world", 11);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1. Here you are using `=` for comparing. `=` is used for assignment and not equality compassion. `==` is used for equality compassion. So, `if((cmd1 = (-1)))` and `if(cmd1=(0))` should have been `if((cmd1 == (-1)))` and `if(cmd1 == (0))`
2. You are checking if the returned value is -1 for failure. This is incorrect. Exit code for success is 0 for failure is any value other than 0. So, `if((cmd1 = (-1)))` should have been `if(cmd1 != 0)`.

Comment: Hey thanks I'll correct `cmd1!=0, about using `=` instead of `==` is an stupid error, I'm feel asleep at that hour.